# In an app, would alerts and message be strange if "S'il vous plait" was used?

Tags: informatique, politesse

I am a computer programmer and am adding French to one of my apps. Would it be strange to use "s'il vous plait" for alerts, and therefore, should I use "Veuillez"?

For example, when an actions fails, the message is:

> Il y avait une erreur. S'il vous plaît, vérifiez votre connexion à internet et réessayez.

Is this strange? Should it be the following instead?

> Il y avait une erreur. Veuillez vérifier votre connexion à internet et réessayer.

If so, I will have a million message to change. I would prefer my app feel more natural, rather than an Anglophone app translated.

Comment: Effectivement, l'utilisation de "Veuillez" est bien plus cohérente. Vous ne verrez jamais un message contenant "S'il vous plaît" dans une application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it will be strange if you use the phrase “S'il vous plait”, you should use “veuillez”, by the way a better message would be like this:

> Une erreur s'est produite, veuillez vérifier votre connexion internet et réessayer.

Comment: Or : Une erreur s'est produite. Veuillez vérifier votre connexion Internet et réessayer.